# Joint density of order statistics $f_{X_{(1)}X_{(n)}}(x,y)$ with combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

#### Problem

I need to find $f_{X_{(1)}X_{(n)}}(x,y)$ for the uniform distribution. $X_{(k)}$ denotes the $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest from an n-sample. I already know that the answer is

$f_{X_{(1)}X_{(n)}}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
 n(n-1)f(x)f(y)(F(y)-F(x))^{n-2} & x<y \\
 0 & x\geq  y
\end{cases}$

I need to be able to do this with a sort of combinatorial derivation. (Edit: without calculus)

Need to derive it for the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ then it can be extended to the general case.

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x,y)=\text{P}(X_{(1)}\in[x,x+h),X_{(n)}\in[y,y+h))=\frac{n!}{1!(n-2)!1!}\text{P}(\cap_{k=2}^{n-1} \{x+h\leq X_{(k)}\leq y\})\text{P}(X_{(1)}\in[x,x+h))\text{P}(X_{(n)}\in[y,y+h))$$
$$=n(n-1)(y-x-h)^{n-2}h^2$$

I am unsure that this is correct. is $f(x)=h$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call "combinatorial" is not clear to me (in particular I see very little combinatorics in the solution you suggest) but the simplest approach to your problem might be to consider, for every $0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant1$, the event $A_{x,y}=[x\leqslant X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\leqslant y]$. Then:

- $A_{x,y}=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n[x\leqslant X_k\leqslant y]$ hence $\mathbb P(A_{x,y})=$ $____$.
- The density $g$ of $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is such that $g(x,y)=-\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}\mathbb P(A_{x,y})$ hence $g(x,y)=$ $____$.

The same technique applies to every i.i.d. sample with a densitable distribution $f$ and CDF $F$ and yields a simple formula for $g$ as a function of $f$ and $F$.

Comment: I have recently made the question shorter so that it might be answered - which seems to have worked. The original had the derivation by taking partial derivatives in it. By combinatorial I mean not with calculus, by counting and proving for the uniform distribution. If I can prove it for the uniform distribution it is easy to extend.

Comment: As an example: the proof that if $X$ has density $f(x)$ then $f_{X_{(k)}}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}(F_{X}(x)^{k-1}(1-F_X(x))^{n-k}f(x)$ This is done by taking an $n$-sample of $(Y_j)_{j=1}^n$, the event $A_k(y,h) \equiv \{Y_{(k)}\in(y,y+h]\}$, $B_1 \equiv \{$ one $Y_j\in(y,y+h]\}$ and $B_2\equiv\{$more than one $Y_j\in(y,y+h]\}$ Then showing that $\text{P}(A_k(y,h)\cap B_2)=\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ and $\text{P}(A_k(y,h)\cap B_1)= \frac{n!}{(k-1)!1!(n-k)!}y^{k-1}(1-y-h)^{n-k} h$ thus proving it for $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$

Comment: So my interpretation of that is that it is analogous to the way we can find a derivative in an elementary fashion, a similar thing is done here - instead we are seeing how the probabilities change with respect to small difference its the parameter $x$ of an event $\{Y_j \in [x,x+h)\}$. So we can ignore things $~\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ because it is similar (or the same?), also we get the same result by counting i.e. the ways to split n things into 3 sections of size $k-1$, $1$ and $n-k$ is $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!1!(n-k)!}$

Comment: @Did: Could you please explain the $-\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$ part? I am unable to see why that is so.

Comment: @Shyam Assume that $g$ exists and write down $P(A_{x,y})$ as an integral of $g$. Then differentiate with respect to the bounds of the integral.

Comment: @shilov Is the purpose of your comments to rejoice that my post answers your question or to signal that it does not?

Comment: @Shyam: I see... Thanks :)